# Proving that $1<10^{\frac{1}{10}}$

Tags: inequality

I was inspired by the $9^\sqrt{2} \text{ v.s. }\sqrt2^9$ problem and so I decided to make one of my own. Taking a look at a graph of $x^{\frac{1}{x}}$, I could see that $\sqrt[10]{10}>1$. But how do I prove this? I will write my own answer, hopefully there are other answers too.

Comment: For $a>1$ function $a^x$ is monotically increasing. We know that $10^0=1$, so $10^\frac{1}{10}>1$.

Comment: Just take the $10^{th}$ power of both sides.

Comment: Or, take the logarithm, base $10$, of both sides.

Comment: Decreasing after $x=e$ and its limit at $\infty$ is $1$. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%3Dx%5E%281%2Fx%29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, "$10^{1/10}$" means the (positive real) number which, times itself 10 times, equals 10. Obviously $1$ is too small since $1^{10}=1<10$ and $2$ is too big since $2^{10}=1024>10$. Thus $1<10^{1/10}<2$. By picking the right fractions, instead of $1$ and $2$, you can narrow this range down.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to tackle these questions is to take log both sides base 10. Assuming it to be true (if not true the result will be contradictory, the we'll assume the opposite to be true).
Considering,
$$1<10^{\frac{1}{10}}$$
$$\log_{10}{1}<\frac{1}{10}\log_{10}{10}$$
$$0<\frac{1}{10}$$
Which is true hence your inequality is true.